# Unable to deploy spring boot application in linux through Azure app service

Tags: linux, azure, spring-boot, tomcat8, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm trying to build a application in spring boot and deploy through azure appservice. We decided to go with linux kernel and followed same steps from the below links. The two links are different in steps but still i was not able to get the application up on linux. The same app works fine on Windows os and app started working.
Project is referred from git shared in below url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?view=azure-java-stable

https://medium.com/@k32y/spring-boot-deployment-on-azure-app-service-zero-code-approach-88305c8d0818

Do we need to have extra config for linux?
Note:
While deploying on windows, web.config  is created automatically while on linux it doesn't create.

## POM XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>  
    <relativePath/>  
    <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
  </parent>  
  <groupId>com.amock</groupId>  
  <artifactId>hello-azure</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <name>hello-azure</name>  
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <description>Spring Boot Hello World On Azure</description>  
  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
  </properties>  
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>  
  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: If you follow the azure tutorial, please share you pom.xml, mostly it's the runtime problem.

Comment: used a generated pom from start.spring.io and added web,thymeleaf dependencies